# Establish Salesforce API should not be sent more than N requests per second

Tags: api, limits

I want to establish that my salesforce API don't sent more than N request per second, someone have idea on how to establish this limit?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a minute to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you've tried so far and where you are stuck. This could be showing the research you've done or code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you need to ensure that all your outgoing messages are processed through a queuing mechanism with a single consumer that takes messages off the queue and sends them, but ensuring that only *n* messages are sent per second.

You could probably adapt the mechanism I've covered in [this article](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/) as follows:

1. Create an object that holds the outgoing message detail.
2. Create and insert outgoing message records when you want to queue a message to be sent.
3. Each time one or more is created, publish a platform event (from the trigger for this outgoing message object).
4. Have an apex trigger based subscriber for the platform event that:

   1. Queries up to *n* outgoing message records in ascending CreatedDate order.
   2. Sends the messages these records represent.
   3. Deletes the "sent" message records.
   4. If there are more records representing messages to be sent, publishes the same type of platform event again. This will cause the subscriber trigger to be called again after a delay.

This should do what you need since platform event chaining always has a minimum of 1 second delay between executions of your subscriber code.

Note that *n* would be limited to 100 in this case since you can only do 100 callouts from a given transaction. You can resolve this by jumping into separate transactions for each chunk of 100 in that second by enqueuing of queueables or similar.